# Google sheets timestamp via apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Let me start by saying that I am very new to google apps script and JavaScript. I am writing a script that will timestamp when column 13 gets its status changed to "Accepted" or "In Progress" from a dropdown list, and then put the timestamp into col 24 or 25, depending on which status was selected. It also checks to see if there is already text in the target cell.

My problem is that the first part works fine, selecting "Accepted" will enter the timestamp exactly as it should, but nothing happens when I select "In Progress". I think that this is probably due to my {} bracket placement but I was unable to puzzle it out myself. Input would be greatly appreciated.

````
function onEdit(e) {  

  addTimestamp(e);

  
}

function addTimestamp(e){
  //variables
  var startRow = 3;
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var targetColumn = 13;
  var ws = "Call Log";
  var ss = "Copy of Project Worksheets (for testing)";
  //get modified row and column
  var row = e.range.getRow();  //value for row
  var col = e.range.getColumn(); //value for the column
  
    if(col === targetColumn && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws) { 
// Checks the name of the sheet you are working on, in this case its Call log.
      if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,13).getValue() =="Accepted"){
        if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,24).getValue() =="")
          e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,24).setValue(currentDate);}
        
      if (e.source.getActivesheet().getRange(row,13).getValue() =="In Progress"){
        if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,25).getValue() =="")
          e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,25).setValue(currentDate);}
  } // END IF check column, row, and worksheet name
 } // END IF function addTimestamp```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo error in `getActivesheet()`

Change:

```
if (e.source.getActivesheet().getRange(row,13).getValue() =="In Progress")
```

to

```
if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,13).getValue() =="In Progress")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I guess I just needed an extra set of eyes. It works perfectly after that.

Comment: No problem. I was able to detect the issue by luck :). I copied the syntax where the code is failing and tried to check the value in the logs `Logger.log(e.source.getActivesheet().getRange(row,13).getValue())` which returned an error when checking the execution tab